# Trouble installing GasFluxes Package in R Studio

Tags: r, r-library

I plan on using the package gasfluxes

I installed it

```
install.packages("gasfluxes")
```

which returns

> trying URL
> 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/gasfluxes_0.4-4.tgz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 586415 bytes (572 KB)
> ================================================== downloaded 572 KB
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> /var/folders/57/yzcztp0s57sfbcbb0zd81j9w0000gn/T//Rtmpt030MZ/downloaded_packages

then I go to add it to the library which returns this error

```
library(gasfluxes)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gasfluxes’ in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘unmarked’

Not sure what I can do to remedy this problem. Any help would be appreciated. I tried reinstalling R. I'm not sure what is causing this error so I'm not sure where to start. Other packages are working without any issue.

Comment: did you try installing the package ```unmarked``` ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue out myself. I did not understand the error. I was under the impression the package was not in the correct place thus it was "unmarked". Unmarked is a separate package I had to install as it was a dependency I think.